# Map view Html controls to specific action object MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping

I have this action

```
public ActionResult Index(int id,int name, SomeObject object)
{
        //SomeCode
}
```

and the `SomeObject class`

```
public class SomeObject
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public int Name {get; set;}
}
```

my `View`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.TextBox("id", "")
@Html.TextBox("name", "")

@Html.TextBox("object_id", "")
@Html.TextBox("object_name", "")

<button class="btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

every time I submit I got `object.id and object.name` parameters of `index` action 
have the same values of `id and name`, what can I do to get them correctly?

**Note: I don't want to rename prameters**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your view look like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.TextBox("id", "")
@Html.TextBox("name", "")

@Html.TextBox("object.id", "")
@Html.TextBox("object.name", "")

<button class="btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

Using "." instead of "_" and try another parameter name for "object" :)

Comment: I don't want to change parameters name

Comment: You can not build your project with this code  SomeObject object, I mean that, SomeObject obj ...

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use [`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.id)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) (I am assuming your view had a model bound to it).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.TextBox("id", "")
@Html.TextBox("name", "")

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

<button class="btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

Comment: No I don't have bound for this the model type is different object,